# In the Taproot implementation of Schnorr signatures, is "e" the hash of R or r?

Tags: bitcoin-core, taproot, schnorr-signatures

BIP340 describes the Schnorr signature scheme that will be implemented with Taproot.

The signature scheme involves computing an integer, e, during both signing and verification.

Under Default Signing, e is defined as

> Let e = int(hashBIP0340/challenge(bytes(**R**) || bytes(P) || m)) mod n.

Under Verification, it is defined as

> Let e = int(hashBIP0340/challenge(bytes(**r**) || bytes(P) || m)) mod n.

It seems to me that a the signature is valid only if e has an unambiguous definition.

Does it use the curve point, R, or its x-coordinate, r?

Link to the BIP340-documentation: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki

Answer (score 3):

The `bytes()` function is defined in [BIP 340](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki#specification) as:

> The function bytes(x), where x is an integer, returns the 32-byte
> encoding of x, most significant byte first.
>
> The function bytes(P), where P is a point, returns bytes(x(P)).

Hence the `bytes()` function of a point is defined to return the same as the `bytes()` function of the x coordinate. The y coordinate is thrown away in the case that a point is fed into the `bytes()` function.

Comment: This clarifies it. Thank you!